# What happened to the directives property in the Component decorator for Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-cli

I am using the [Angular CLI v1.0.0-beta.19-3](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to scaffold/build an Angular 2 website. I generate my component as follows `ng g component file-upload`.

I noticed that the generated component `file-upload.component.ts` looks like the following.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
}
```

I need to use this component, [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload), inside my own component. So I try to add the `directives` property on the `@Component` decorator, however, I get an error in [VS Code](http://code.visualstudio.com).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css'],
  directives: [ FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES ]
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
}
```

```
[ts] Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; styleUrls: string[]; directives: undefined[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.
```

And my imports look like the following.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgClass, NgStyle } from '@angular/common';
import { FileSelectDirective, FileDropDirective, FileUploadModule, FileUploader, FileUploaderOptions } from 'ng2-file-upload';
```

When I run the app `ng serve`, I see the following error reported in the console.

```
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
  [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
  (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
  [ERROR ->][uploader]="uploader"
  class="well my-drop-zone">
```

Here's my dependencies in `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "app-www",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.6",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
    "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

The doc says to use this import statement.

```
import { FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-file-upload';
```

But in VS Code, it says the following.

```
[ts] Module '"/Users/jwayne/git/app-www/node_modules/ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload"' has no exported member 'FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES'.
```

What's even more interesting, is that I created my own login component like the following.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login-component',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
}
```

In order to use this in another component, I don't even have to reference it as a directive or anything like that anymore. For example, I have a default component that uses this login component. The HTML looks like the following.

```
<login-component></login-component>
```

And the code looks like the following (note no directive property for the component decorator).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-default',
  templateUrl: './default.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./default.component.css']
})
export class DefaultComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 ...
}
```

Although the `app.module.ts` file is modified now.

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DefaultComponent } from './default/default.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DefaultComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'default', component: DefaultComponent },
      { path: 'main', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [ UserAuthGuard ] },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/default', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/default' }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [ 
    UserAuthGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So, there's a lot of stuff going on, but to start off, what happened to the directives property for the component decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solving this problem was importing the directives in `app.module.ts` and then declaring them with `@NgModule`. Here's a snippet of `app.module.ts`.

```
import { FileSelectDirective, FileDropDirective} from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FileSelectDirective, FileDropDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'default', component: DefaultComponent },
      { path: 'main', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [ UserAuthGuard ] },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/default', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/default' }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In my component, I still had to import the directives. Here's another snippet.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgClass, NgStyle } from '@angular/common';
import { 
  FileSelectDirective,
  FileDropDirective, 
  FileUploader, 
  FileUploaderOptions 
} from 'ng2-file-upload';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { LoginService } from '../service/login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  //body omitted
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the docs were using an older RC version of Angular. In the meantime the angular team introduced the concept of `NgModule`s to better structure your app and to avoid repeating your used directives. So you no longer declare the directives used in the `Component` decorator. For details on this, please have a look at the [angular docs on NgModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html).

The library you are using also adapted to this but probably the docs didn't change yet. Check [their demo code](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/tree/development/demo) and [this commit](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/commit/e9d356b1ce3387d3abf1afa25262db968d629312#diff-49f44bede38d49c982cf295579f175f9) in the repository to see how you need to import the module now and also have a look at the API changes.