# nested Components in angular2

Tags: angular, web, single-page-application, angular2-components

I'm going to upgrade my knowledge of angular2 from version **Rc5** to **2.2**.
I have problem with directive property that had been deprecated since i upgraded my packages.I know it moves to **imports** property on NgModule decorator but it called **Shared Components** but when i have very large number of components that i have to move from directives on every component to starting point of my app at NgModule and therefor all of my Components have to Load at start,i don't know if there is a way to bring back directives to Components to lazy load Components inside other Components.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293240/how-to-manually-lazy-load-a-module/40293482#40293482

Comment: its not my question,i want to load Component inside Components not a module . my question is like this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589177/what-happened-to-the-directives-property-in-the-component-decorator-for-angular but i dont want to load all of my components at starting point at NgModules imports

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's still the answer to your question. Components are loaded by modules. Lazy loading is done on module level. That's how the new world looks like.

Comment: so you are going to tell me to separate my Components into ngModules and load them with loader

Comment: Exactly  . . . . .... . . .

Comment: very nice thanks but directives was better to lazy load every private component that was relative to just one Component

Comment: There were lots of issues with lazy loading. This was what they come up with after quite a lot of different attempts during beta phase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129969/discussion-between-mohammad-mc-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my friend told,nesting components in angular has been deprecated and instead Module loading comes inside. here's how I implement that in my way:
first,I found that we can lazy load a module with new router,so i Modularize areas of my app and change my main module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {homeComponent} from './appComponent/homeComponent.Component'
import { AppComponent }  from './appComponent/app.component';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: homeComponent },
      { path: 'lazy1', loadChildren: './dist/app/detailComponent/detailModule.Module#detailModule' }

    ], {})
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,homeComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Last root route shows that how we can asign a Module instead of imported Component,and then we configure our child routes in second module and act like this:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { DetailComponent } from '../detailComponent/detail.component'
import { RouterModule, Route, Router} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports:[ RouterModule.forChild([ {path: '', component: DetailComponent}])],
  declarations: [ DetailComponent ]
})
export class detailModule { }
```

as this code shows we can configure our second level module to load its components and use it to reduce network load a little at first (using `systemjs`) and load it as user clicks the menu links.
Note that we can continue nesting our modules in the second level module routing configuration

Also we can load a Module and its Components with builtin angular class named [`SystemJsNgModuleLoader`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/SystemJsNgModuleLoader-class.html)